# VS View Table Data - How to Expand Width of Last Column?

Tags: visual-studio

I am looking at table data in VS (2013) and trying to view the contents of the last column.

Normally you hover over a column border and it gives you an horizontal arrows cursor, to indicate that you can drag the column to the desired width.

But I just can't get it to work on this final column - the one that borders the Solution Explorer window. (Hiding the SE window doesn't help, either).

Adjusting the left column border just narrows the previous column, and doesn't expand the width of the next one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but I have found a way to do it.  *If anyone can provide a better way I'd like to hear it.*

By removing some of the previous columns from the table, the final column no longer borders the Solution Explorer and therefore can be dragged / extended.

To do this, click the filter button just above the table, and deselect some of the boxes.

[image]